# CSV import updates wrong attribute

Tags: magento-1.7, import

We have a dropdown attribute named `product_dimmable` which is set to a value of "Yes" for a product.

When we import the following CSV file the `product_dimmable` value gets reset to the default value of "No" for no apparent reason:

```
sku,price
80179,29.99
```

We are using the standard import method for Magento CE 1.7.0.2.

Does anyone know why this happens and how it can be prevented?

Comment: There are two ways to import data out-of-box. If you're not using the Dataflow option, try using that. It should not be updating any other attributes than `price` in your example. If it is, you probably have customization done somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested this on both default Magento 1.7 and Magento 1.9 and the issue only occurs on 1.7 if the attribute is a dropdown type with a default value. If no default value is set for the attribute, the value is not lost when running an import.

The solution is therefore to make sure that none of the values for the dropdown are set to be the default.